# Google backend oAuth with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, google-api

I query Google Calendar a program written in Python 2.7, **in server to server mode** (using a certificate). Typically like this:

```
        with open('mycertfromgoogleconsole.p12', 'rb') as f:
            private_key = f.read()
        credentials = oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
            'something@developer.gserviceaccount.com,
            private_key,
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
            sub='theaccounttoimpersonate@example.com'
        )
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = apiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)
```

I now need to port the script to Python 3.4 but cannot find a library which would support the backend version of oAuth (there are several which seem to support the web version one). Would you know is there is one available? (ideally a drop-in replacement but that would be close to miraculous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, the code below follows the Google API documentation and the last request yields the token data mentioned in "Handling the response" in the docs above

```
import requests
import jwt
import arrow
import OpenSSL.crypto


class GetToken(object):
    """
    Get Google API token as documented at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.expires = 0
        self.token = None

    def gettoken(self):
        now = arrow.now().timestamp
        # is the token still valid and exists ? (within a 10 seconds margin)
        if now < (self.expires - 10) and self.token:
            return self.token
        self.expires = now + 3600
        claim = {
            "iss": "dev_account_from_google_console@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
            "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
            "exp": now,
            "iat": now,
            "sub": "account_with_delegated_rights@example.com"
        }
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(open('certificate_from_google_api_console.p12', 'rb').read(), 'notasecret')
        private_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()).decode('utf-8')
        myjwt = jwt.encode(claim, private_key, algorithm='RS256', headers={"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT"}).decode('utf-8')
        data = {
            "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
            "assertion": myjwt
        }
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", data=data, headers=headers)
        print(r.json())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = GetToken()
    t.gettoken()
```